# Which topics are hot in computational science?

Tags: numerical-analysis, parallel-computing, software

I am accepted to computational science master program. The master program just started to accept students in our university and today each group of 3 students was assigned to an advisor teacher (we are only 13 students). Our advisor asked us to research for valuable topics in Computational Science, so I thought why don't I ask to experienced scientists in this forum.

My group is combined of 1 electronics engineer (me), 1 mathematician and 1 computer engineer. So, our strengths are math and software programming.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.Exchange. Your question is wide and mostly opinion based, then, maybe this is not the best place to ask. Have you checked the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_science) in the topic?

Comment: Another good starting point is to check some of the talks in a conference related to the topic, for example, [SIAM's CSE](http://www.siam.org/meetings/cse15/).

Comment: While your question is, indeed, a very interesting one to many people on this site, I agree with nicoguaro.  A lot could be said on this one question, but there is no one "canonical answer" to this question.  This site is designed to address specific questions with concrete, specific answers; not for open-ended questions.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Apologies for such open-end question. We are currently heading to computational electromagnetism and optics field. Thanks to @nicoguaro though, the webpage helped a lot.